# Switching from Past Simple to Present Perfect in consecutive sentences

Tags: tense-agreement

Let's imagine someone writing to his buddy:

> 1. Yesterday, I **read** an article in a newspaper.
> 2. I **learned** that our town **became** the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.

The Simple Past in sentence 1 is understandable: a particular time (yesterday) is mentioned.
Should one retain the Simple Past for "learned" and for "became"?

Or is it okay to switch to Present Perfect, and go on with the Present Perfect, since the information is new and has relation to the present moment:

> 2. I'**ve learned** that our town **has become** the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.
> 3. It **has outstripped** even Moscow and St. Petersburg!

Or is it better to keep "learned" in Simple Past, since the learning occured within the same timeframe as the reading mentioned in sentence 1, but switch to Present Perfect after it:

> 2. I **learned** that our town **has become** the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.
> 3. It **has outstripped** even Moscow and St. Petersburg!

I'm curious to know from which moment is it allowable to break loose of the use of the Past Simple commanded by the existence of a particular timeframe in sentence 1 and to start relaying novel information in Present Perfect.

Comment: I think, the sequence of tenses is incorrect in the latter example. As it follows from your latter example, you had learned about it earlier than the article was written and ,therefore, than the rating of towns was actually prepared. So you are a prophet!

Comment: Your second and first examples are ok, because they do not emphasize what occured earlier.

Comment: I think keeping simple past tense at both times (learnt and became) should be correct. I tried it with some sentences and i am more than convinced that it is correct.

Comment: Hi. This comes pretty close to proofreading question. Do you have specific concerns about the past versus present perfect? At any rate, your third set sounds best. Learned goes with read (past). Meanwhile, use *has become/outstripped* unless those facts are no longer true.

Comment: But there may be a difference between BrE and AmE as to preference for the tense of learned. I think BrE uses present perfect more.

Comment: @CarSmack So "has become" is distanced enough from "read" to be in the Present Perfect, but "learned" still belongs to the same timeframe. Thanks!

Comment: That is the way I would most likely write it. The *distance* you refer to is, in my mind, the "distance" between your two simple past actions (read, learned) that you did and the facts about your town, which are still true when you read about them.

Comment: @ CarSmack *At any rate, your third set sounds best.* Really? Doesn't such sequence of tenses show what event happened earlier? I've always thought that past simple before present perfect is used intentionally to show that the first event is prior to the second one. Some links to the relevant rule would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why someone needs to use the past simple followed by the present perfect in such a context? Is there any need for this usage? Why not say the same, using only the present perfect or only the past simple?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a lot of tenses in the English language and you use them, not taking enough care over the sequence of events.

Comment: @Humbulani: because "the town's becoming the first" is news, it could be more proper to use Present Perfect to stress that fact.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The first event 1)  the town has become the first. ///The second event 2 ) you have learned about it, haven't you?

Comment: @Humbulani - the hitch is that you cannot say "I have learned [something] yesterday". Mentioning the precise timeframe ("yesterday") forces you to employ Simple Past.

Comment: @ CopperKettle So what? You said: "I learned that our town has become the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life." You didn't mention 'yesterday' in this sentence, right?"

Comment: @Humbulani - Right, but that *learned* still logically belongs to the same timeframe: I learned the same moment I read, otherwise I would be considered a rather slow coach. Hence "I read and I learned yesterday", as it were.

Comment: @  CopperKettle *otherwise I would be considered a rather slow coach* Why? Do you really think that English speakers would consider you a slowpoke in this case?

Comment: @Humbulani See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious to know from which moment is it allowable to break loose of the use of the Past Simple commanded by the existence of a particular timeframe in sentence 1 and to start relaying novel information in Present Perfect.

**Short answer:** after the initial *read,* you can switch freely between *simple past* and *present perfect.*  If you use *have learned* you are considering that to be part of the novel information.

Ex 4.
(Yesterday/today/just now,) I **read** an article in a newspaper.
I **(have) learned** that our town **became/has become** the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.
It **(has) outstripped** even Moscow and St. Petersburg!

So, even the following are okay:

Ex 5.
(Yesterday/today/just now,) I **read** an article in a newspaper.
I **have learned** that our town **became** the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.
It **has outstripped** even Moscow and St. Petersburg!

Ex 6.
(Yesterday/today/just now,) I **read** an article in a newspaper.
I **learned** that our town **has become** the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.
It **outstripped** even Moscow and St. Petersburg!

Some of the following is written with the comments of **Humbulani** in mind:

After *read,* you are free to switch back and forth between the *simple past* and *present perfect* because this is a simple scenario with, at most, four things occurring.

First thing, (a) you read. You have established this with the *simple past* tense.

Either simultaneously or consequently to reading, (b) you learned. You can express this in *simple past* in parallel to the reading, or you can express this in *present perfect* as 'novel information' you are reporting.

The only other two bits of novel information you are reporting happened at the same time: (c) 'our town' is #1, and (d) 'our town' is before Moscow and Peter. They happened at the same time because the list indicating both facts was published at the same time.

You are free to report (c) and (d) using either the *simple past* or *present perfect* in any combination. Since (c) and (d) happened at the same time, your use of *past* and *present perfect* does not establish a time sequence between them, it reports your 'attitude' toward the events, as past events (simple past) or as past events connected with the present (present perfect).

You can do this with or without *yesterday* in the first sentence—as long as the word 'read' means the past tense (as opposed to 'read' that means present tense). You could have read the newspaper *today* or *ten seconds ago.* By using *today,* it is automatically inferred that you mean *earlier today,* since you use the past tense. You can even say *just now,* but everyone knows you mean *a little time in the past.*

In addition, that (c) and (d) happened before either (a) or (b) is understood from context, common sense, our knowledge of the world, and the grammatical construction used to report information.

Comment: So, if we say: "I learned that our town has become the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life", this is perfectly correct. The past simple followed by the present perfect here shows nothing about what happened earlier, and this plays another role. In this context, we rely only on common sense to understand what was the first and what was the next.

Comment: If I get it right, in general, the past simple used together with the present perfect does not influence our understanding of the sequence of events. One event was the first to happen in the past, but it has been related with the present until now (town has become). The other event happened after the first one (he read and learned). But we can speak about it in the simple past tense.

Answer (score 1):

> Yesterday, I read an article in a newspaper. I learned that our town
>   became the first in a list of towns ranked by quality of life.

Here's how I'd expect the above in American English.

**Yesterday, I read an article...Our town has been ranked #1 for quality-of-life.**

or

**Yesterday, I read an article...... Our town was ranked #1 for quality-of-life.**

To my ear, using the present perfect makes my statement about the *town*;  using the past makes my statement about the article.